# INNER join taking way too long

Tags: mysql, algorithm, inner-join

I asked the original question here [in stack before.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54833508/use-a-single-query-to-pull-from-mulitple-tables) Apologies if this is not the best way to go about this.

The problem is I have a query that even with a INNER JOIN is taking at least 5 seconds to complete and I'm wondering if there is a faster way to do this. Here is the answer I was given:

```
` q = "SELECT DISTINCT e2.eventId FROM event_tags e1 INNER JOIN event_tags e2 " \
        "ON BINARY e2.tagName=e1.tagName AND e2.eventId != e1.eventId " \
        "WHERE e1.eventId = {} ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT {}".format(eventId, '10')`
```

my tags table looks like this

```
mysql> describe event_tags;

+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| tagId   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| tagName | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| eventId | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and I have a bunch of tags in them and they will only continue to grow. When I do a count on the tags table I have 504,402 tagId, and same for tagname. How could I make the look up faster?

Here is some sample data of the event tags table

```
mysql> select * from event_tags limit 40;
+-------+-------------------------------------------+---------+
| tagId | tagName                                   | eventId |
+-------+-------------------------------------------+---------+
|   261 | Justin Timberlake (Rescheduled from 11/9) |      38 |
|   264 | Rogers Arena                              |      38 |
|   267 | Pop                                       |      38 |
|   271 | Rock                                      |      38 |
|   285 | Justin Timberlake (Rescheduled from 11/8) |      41 |
|   288 | Rogers Arena                              |      41 |
|   291 | Pop                                       |      41 |
|   294 | Rock                                      |      41 |
|   595 | Yogesh Soman                              |      84 |
|   599 | Geetanjali Kulkarni                       |      84 |
|   602 | Bhagyashree Shankpal                      |      84 |
|   606 | Lalit Prabhakar                           |      84 |
|   611 | Sameer Sanjay Vidwans                     |      84 |
|   617 | Drama                                     |      84 |
|   647 | Shrihari Abhyankar                        |      89 |
|   651 | Deepali Borkar                            |      89 |
|   654 | Akash Kamble                              |      89 |
|   657 | Sharavi Kulkarni                          |      89 |
|   660 | Sharav Wadhawekar                         |      89 |
|   667 | Nipun Dharmadhikari                       |      89 |
|   670 | Drama                                     |      89 |
|   689 | Frank Grillo                              |      94 |
|   692 | Jamie Bell                                |      94 |
|   695 | Margaret Qualley                          |      94 |
|   700 | James Badge Dale                          |      94 |
|   704 | Tim Sutton                                |      94 |
|   710 | Drama                                     |      94 |
|   734 | Bruce Dern                                |     101 |
|   739 | Anthony Michael Hall                      |     101 |
|   745 | Sean Astin                                |     101 |
|   749 | Aly Michalka                              |     101 |
|   754 | Victoria Smurfit                          |     101 |
|   759 | Carl Bessai                               |     101 |
|   762 | Drama                                     |     101 |
|   783 | Sarah Clarke                              |     106 |
|   785 | Xander Berkeley                           |     106 |
|   787 | Kristen Gutoskie                          |     106 |
|   790 | Mackenzie Astin                           |     106 |
|   794 | Bobby Campo                               |     106 |
|   798 | Adam Cushman                              |     106 |
+-------+-------------------------------------------+---------+
40 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and here is the CREATE statement for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS event_tags(
    tagId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    tagName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    eventId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(tagId, eventId)
);
```

Here is the EXPLAIN for the query:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT e2.eventId FROM event_tags e1 INNER JOIN event_tags e2 ON BINARY e2.tagName=e1.tagName AND e2.eventId != e1.eventId WHERE e1.eventId = 487 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
    -> ;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e1    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 34275 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e2    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 34275 | Using where; Using join buffer               |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

UPDATE: i created an index on the table with:

```
CREATE INDEX tagsNdx ON event_tags (eventId, tagName(255));
```

Which looks now like this:

`mysql> show index from event_tags;
+------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| event_tags |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | tagId       | A         |      455408 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| event_tags |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | eventId     | A         |      455408 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| event_tags |          1 | tagsNdx  |            1 | eventId     | A         |         186 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| event_tags |          1 | tagsNdx  |            2 | tagName     | A         |         186 |      255 | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

But it's still slow.

Comment: A composite index on some combination of (tagname,eventid) might help. Also, this is MyISAM, which is rather unfashionable now. It might be an idea to switch to InnoDB, and have the AI on tagid alone.

Comment: @Strawberry I thought since eventId was already a primary key that the lookup would be reasonably fast.

Comment: You're trying to join every row with every other row of the same name, then order the entire inermediate result randomly; unless those tagNames are not repeated very often, I would expect this kind of query to get exponentially worse as the table grows... though indexing tagName would probably help quite a bit.

Comment: @Uueerdo actually he is only joinning rows with same tag. So as long there is an index for `tagName`  should be fast

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza there is no tagId comparison in the query they presented.

Comment: I saw your linked question, and there you use `LIKE '%  ... %'` that comparasion can't use index and will be slow

Comment: @Uueerdo there is `e2.tagName=e1.tagName`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes, but there are no constraints or indexes on tagName.

Comment: @stingMantis Can you add some sample data to your question? and the actual CREATE statement for the table.

Comment: Looking at your original question, it looks like the answer you were provided is really your best option; a LIKE condition with a leading wildcard will almost always have subpar performance.

Comment: Thank you all for responding thus far. I've added the create statement and some sample data from the table.

Comment: As said, you you please post the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`. Also I think the `ORDER BY RAND()` creates a filesort which is slow.

Comment: Just create an index  `CREATE INDEX idx1 ON event_tags  (eventId , tagName)`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Is this still fine given that the tagId and the eventId are already primary keys?

Comment: I just edit my comment, because you have a filter `e1.eventId = 487` is better a composite index with `(eventId , tagName)`

Comment: The index sounds like a good idea. I've updated my original question to show how I added it but unfortunetly it is still taking about 5 seconds for the results. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Following is possible optimization:

1. Remove column "eventId" from primary key (this step is optional an can be further elaborated if you like).
2. Create index on column (eventId,tag_name).
3. Execute Command:  ANALYZE TABLE event_tags

Comment: I updated my post to show the table after adding the index. I'm still getting a slow results though.

Comment: Query Cost and time should decrease after index creation no mater if not very substantial otherwise the index is not being used. Also the before and after time is to be taken after dropping session cache else data will be reused from cache and would not give true comparison.

Comment: Also plz tell how many distinct eventid and how many distinct tag_name in the table

Comment: there are 7266 rows in set (0.00 sec) for the eventIds and 12346 rows in set (0.01 sec) for the tagName. Will i have to refactor this table you think?

Comment: there are 117792 rows in set (0.19 sec) for the eventIds and 105008 rows in set (2.11 sec) for the tagName. Will i have to refactor this table you think? EdIT: ADDED CORRECT VALUES FOR eventId and tagName

Comment: Our new index is not being used and there can be many reasons including one regarding old statistics. Use command : ANALYZE TABLE event_tags

Comment: mysql> analyze table event_tags;
+----------------------+---------+----------+----------+
| Table                | Op      | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+----------------------+---------+----------+----------+
| <dbname>.event_tags | analyze | status   | OK       |
+----------------------+---------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)